# How to induce large current in a flexible wire

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-current, electromagnetic-induction

I have not tested this method in the lab or anything, but based on what I know about electrodynamics I would say the following set up could work:

I would take two straight flexible free-of-current wires and wrap them around a cylindrical form, ending up with two coils. I would model them in such a way that the same flux would pass through each turn of both coils.

At this point I would change the current of one of the coils (from $0$ to $I$), which would change the flux passing through the free-of-current coil (the one I did not apply current to) and thus an emf would be induced in this second coil.

$$\varepsilon= -\frac{d \Phi}{dt}$$

If we were to induce a large current in the second coil we would just have to apply a large current in the first coil.

**Is there any other easier way to induce a large current on a flexible wire?** For instance, a method that avoids having to deform the wires.

Comment: You've described a transformer. I think one would always want to loop the wires so that the most wires (in this case, turns) would pass through a given section of flux.

Comment: Like Digiproc says, this basically what a transformer is. However, you would need to connect the two ends of the 2nd wire, or place a load of some kind between them, in order to get a current in the second wire (aka, the transformer's *secondary* coil).

Comment: Next point (somewhat pedantic), we say the EMF is induced in the secondary coil. We don't use the word *induced* when talking about the secondary current.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Digiproc says in comments, you're basically describing a *transformer*.

However, one thing you didn't mention in your description, is you would need to connect the two ends of the 2nd wire (which we can call the *secondary* coil of the transformer), or place a load of some kind between them, in order to get a current in the secondary.

> Is there any other easier way to induce a large current on a flexible wire?

You could simply ignore your first wire and connect your current source directly to the second wire.

You can make a transformer with only a single loop in the secondary. Or even with a straight wire near a high-current primary (this can be done with a wire on the ground to illegally steal power from overhead high tension lines, for example). But this will not be nearly as effective as forming the secondary into multiple loops, and you would still have to connect some load or short circuit between the two ends of the wire, which would probably require bending it somewhat.